# Reactstrap tooltip enable/disable based on state of the button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I am using Reactstrap (version 6.5.0) for styling of my ReactJs project.

I have an inline form which has a submit button. This button is disabled until the user has entered the mandatory details in the form.

What I am trying to achieve is the following:

1. User should be shown a `tooltip` when he hovers over the disabled button (i.e he has not filled in the mandatory details).
2. When he fills in the mandatory details, the tooltip should no longer be shown on the submit button.

I am using Reactstrap `UncontrolledTooltip` component as follows

```
    <button id="submitButton" type="submit" onClick={this.onSubmit} className="btn" disabled={this.state.submitButtonDisabled}>Submit</button>
    { this.state.submitButtonDisabled &&
                  <UncontrolledTooltip placement="bottom" target="submitButton">
                       Please fill in the mandatory details
                  </UncontrolledTooltip>
     }
```

My component has `this.state.submitButtonDisabled`state which I toggle based on whether all the mandory feilds are filled in.

However, what is happening is that the `tooltip` is not shown on hover over the disabled `submit` button. It is only shown when I try to click the disabled `submit` button a few times.
Also, once the mandatory details have been filled in and `submit` button becomes enabled, `tooltip` keeps on showing even then on hover.

Edited : I also noticed that clicking the submit button also gives below warning in the console

```
     index.js:1452 Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
```

How can I achieve the expected behaviour using Reactstrap (I don't want to use jquery just for the tooltip)
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code here,

1.

```
<button id="submitButton" type="submit" onClick={this.onSubmit} className="btn" disabled={this.state.submitButtonDisabled}>Submit</button>
```

This piece you are expecting a hover behavior but you have an onClick={this.submit} function which needs to be updated to enable hover - use correct eventlistner.

2. your logical rendering should be an or case, but you are using and case, for eg:

{ this.state.submitButtonDisabled && } should be implemented as

{ this.state.submitButtonDisabled ? : "yes-your yes case code here": 'no-no case code here' } in your case no case is a null.

Hope that give you enough hints to implement your solution.

Answer (score 0):

apparently you cannot bind a function to *disabled*.
`disabled={this.state.submitButtonDisabled()}` should do the trick